Is there a selfie stick with a built-in camera and flash, and if so what is the common term for such a product?
As a non-photographer and not of any close field my problem with connecting a smartphone to a selfie stick and then take still photos with it is that the flash of probably most if not all front cameras of smartphones is not discrete and strong as the regular flashes on the back cameras of smartphones, let alone as strong as regular still photo cameras. They are "continuous and weak" screen flash (not even a camera flash), which I reckon to be too weak with current technology as that it would fail to light a capture in a dimly lit 5 m² room.
A search with several search engines on the term Selfie stick with camera with discrete flash doesn't bring any result matching my description here.
Is there a selfie stick embedded with a camera as one single product combining both devices, that lights with standard flash which is discrete and strong enough to light a capture in a dimly lit room and if so what is the common term for such a product?

Duplicate of What is the term for a flat-camera photographing stick with flash?

The previous post, being much less technically accurate, includes a question in the format of What is the term for products by this description? while this post includes a question in the format of Do products by this description exist and if so what is a term to describe them? These are categorically different questions hence I opine that this is not a duplicate. Even if a mod would indeed consider it a duplicate; I can no longer edit the previous question even if I wanted to (and I don't want to) and I let it be deleted. If you think the current is post is bad, please do downvote.

Very small flash light + close to the subject = very bad photo, usually. Also, selfie sticks are used to shoot oneself with a background, and since flash luminosity decreases as the square of the distance, using a flash on a selfie stick will result in one's face on a dark background.

"I can no longer edit the previous question even if I wanted to" That's because you've created a second account; you can merge them by following this process

@PhilipKendall I am not here to create account or to merge accounts but to ask without an account; some SE sites require an account to ask, some don't and I typically prefer those that don't, it's like editing in Wikipedia without an account, far more convenient for me personally.

First off, no smartphone actually uses a proper strobe. The so-called flash on a smartphone is an LED lamp, more like a video light than a proper strobe. And smartphone cameras for the most part cannot use proper strobes because of their electronic shutters and rolling sensor read out make that nearly impossible. Only $1000+ Profoto strobes can actually do it.
Secondly, there's no truly "discrete" way to use a flash. Flash bursts are obvious, often disruptive, and there's no way to make one unnoticeable or invisible. And the more lightoutput/power you want from a light? The bigger and more noticeable it's going to get.
What you're probably looking for is a different tool, such as a small LED light like a lume cube or small LED light panel and possibly something like a smallrig cage or a glif tripod adapter to attach the light to your phone. But more power and light output would require a larger unit. And to have better control over the light direction and quality, probably something like a CoB LED light which can have modifiers attached to it, and be placed somewhere other than right next to your camera lens.

Is there a selfie stick embedded with a camera as one single product combining both devices, that lights with standard flash which is discrete and strong enough to light a capture in a dimly lit room and if so what is the common term for such a product?

Not that I know of. In photography you're more generally looking for special purpose tools to use together, not all-in-ones to accomplish the tasks you want. Good quality lighting gear, microphones, and support gear are usually separate pieces vs.  the camera. IOW, you'd add a separate light to a separate selfie stick to your camera to get what you want.

"Flash bursts are obvious, often disruptive, and there's no way to make one unnoticeable or invisible." Well, unless they're infrared and the camera is sensitive to IR. Like some surveillance cameras and game cameras.

From the context I'm pretty sure lahiente meant discrete as in separate rather than the flash being inconspicuous

@stativ. that's fair. It's just the overall tone of the question read to me more like  "I want to just by a single device" and a request for an integrated flash as a feature, and discrete is a common typo for discreet.

If you ignore the flash there are stick-like 360 cameras I have seen used.  If you put one of these on the end of an extension the results can be processed down to a view like a camera on a selfie-stick. I've seen youtube videos that seem to use this.
